# OpenDaylight: How to get the Data path ID?

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am attempting to build an SDN app with OpenDaylight. I use the Carbon (latest) release and the OpenFlow plugin. I am trying to use the genius package as it has a lot of support for installing flows and such. I expect multiple switches to connect so I have to specify the "datapath ID" (dpid) in installing the flow. How do I determine the "dpid" when the switch connects?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have look at line number 88 in [this file](https://github.com/opendaylight/netvirt/blob/master/vpnservice/vpnmanager/vpnmanager-impl/src/main/java/org/opendaylight/netvirt/vpnmanager/VpnNodeListener.java), we extract DP id from node connector

Comment: The link is broken, can you please provide details of your answer?